# json call allways returns an error

Tags: php, html, json

I want to perform a simple json call to a php file, but somehow it allways returns an error.

This is my html (the dataString is filled with form values):

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reghandle.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
 $("#modaltitle").html("Welcome");
 $("#errorDetails").html(result.responseText);
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
        },
                    error: function(result){
                 $("#modaltitle").html("Error:");
                 $("#errorDetails").html(result.responseText);
                 $('#myModal').modal('show');
                        }



        });
```

And my php file (I use $num_rows to produce an error or an succes):

```
if ($num_rows>0){
 echo "error and blablabla";
 header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
return json_encode(array("error" => "bad table name"));


 }else{
 echo "ok";
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
return json_encode(array("success" => "blablabla"));


 }
```

If I let my php file produce an error, the modal screen popsup with:

- Title: Error
- Errordetails: error and blablabla

(this is all correct)

And if I let my php file produce a success, the modal screen popsup with:

- Title: Error  (this should be a Welcome message)
- Errordetails: ok

So obiously something goes wrong when returning a success from within my php file, I haven't got a clue what it is though.

Comment: What is a "JSON call"?

Comment: in php write only echo  json_encode(array("success" => "success")); and then still show error?

Comment: Problem solved, the returns in the php file are replaced with echo's. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

`echo "ok";` breaks it on two counts:

- You have to output your HTTP headers **before** you output any content.
- Outputting some free text before the JSON in a JSON document invalidates the JSON

---

You are `return`ing the JSON (it isn't clear if you are returning it anywhere useful) instead of `echo`ing it.

Comment: I've removed both echo's. But the json still returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

because `echo "error and blablabla";` and `echo "ok";`  is not json!
remove these .

Comment: I've removed both echo's. But the json still returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling Jquery that only JSON responses from the server should be treated as successful, but your not sending a JSON response.

So, a few things to note here:

1. You shouldn't output (echo) anything before you set any headers, because the headers have already been sent and so cant be modified.
2. If you do set your headers to say the doc is json, then you should output some json on the page somewhere! (although it still has to be after the headers).
3. Your json_encode statement won't do anything as it only returns. It doesnt output the encoded json data onto the page anywhere.

In short, if you remove the current echo lines, then replace your returns with echos, then it should work.

Comment: on another note, i don't think you actually need to set the json headers at all. Jquery would scan the response anyway.

Comment: I'm kinda lost here..  I've removed both echo's and it stil gives an error in both cases. can you provide me a simple example how my coding should be like? I would appreciate that very much

Comment: @Chris — You can tell the browser you are sending HTML (which PHP will do by default) and then tell jQuery to ignore that and process the data as JSON… but it isn't good practise.